# ICS Overbyte simple HttpProxy

Tags: delphi, http-proxy

I'm doing a simple proxy work, it can listen locally and the requests are forward to a real external online proxy, I tried many but without results.

my online proxy for testing
**194.163.148.227:3128**

There is an IcsHttpProxy tool that is supposed to do this work, but I encountered a lot of obstacles, including there are many options related to security certificates. I do not know what to set in the that when sites can have a lot of differences such as version of certificate, key strength, etc., Do I have to set it manually for each site?

In fact, I did this project using Indy's tools and it done without a problem and without much work and without going into the details of the certificates and what is related to them, but I am interested in doing this project using Overbite ICS tools.

All i need is a simple proxy that forwarding browser requests to an external proxy without entering into the details of security certificates and what is related to them. Is this possible?

My Idea

[image: Text]

Comment: Thanks you for your question, but ICS has a [support forum](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/) at [https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/). It is better to repost your question there.

Comment: And by the way, there is a sample program in ICS distribution that may interest you: OverbyteIcsProxySslServer.dproj. Don't forget to have a look at the comment in front of the source file OverbyteIcsProxySslServer1.pas.

Comment: @fpiette yes, I'm already checked OverbyteIcsProxySslServer1 sample and I make all test on it , and updated INI to what I need but no luck.

Comment: As I said, use [ICS support forum](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/) to ask.

Comment: @fpiette i'm trying to register i haven't received activation email yet.

Comment: @fpiette , after one day trying, proxy works well if set ForwardProxy=True, if set to False not working, i configured target with same HostTag as host(source), what i miss?

Comment: Use [ICS support forum](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/) to get help. There are hundreds of peoples connected there. Be sure to use a real address mail and not an alias. DelphiPraxis host a large number of forums with thousands people. If it doesn't work for you, search what is wrong at you site. I won't react anymore here because I keep repeating the same thing again and again.